# How can I achieve that application remains responsive, while threads work in the background?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have a simple app that will tell me the number of primes within a range:

```
    private void btnMultiThread_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var numbers = Enumerable.Range(2, range - 1);
        var totalPrimes = numbers
            .AsParallel()
            .Where(n => Enumerable.Range(2, (int)Math.Sqrt(n) - 1).All(i => n % i != 0))
            .Count();
        MessageBox.Show(totalPrimes.ToString());
    }
```

The problem is, that while this whole thing is counting, the wpf app remains unresponsive: for example the button I clicked remains pushed in, the application window cannot be moved or even closed.

What do I do, to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: @RandomStranger that would achieve nothing. `async` allows you to *await*. It doesn't make anything run asynchronously

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos my bad, removed my comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't about multithreading per se. `Parallel` and PLINQ use multiple threads *including* the current one to process data in parallel. If you want to avoid blocking you'll have to execute your PLINQ query inside a background task, eg by using Task.Run:

```
private async void btnMultiThread_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var numbers = Enumerable.Range(2, range - 1);
    var totalPrimes = await Task.Run(()=>
        numbers
        .AsParallel()
        .Where(n => Enumerable.Range(2, (int)Math.Sqrt(n) - 1).All(i => n % i != 0))
        .Count());

    MessageBox.Show(totalPrimes.ToString());
}
```

or to make this a bit cleaner:

```
private async void btnMultiThread_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var numbers = Enumerable.Range(2, range - 1);
    var totalPrimes = await Task.Run(()=>CalculatePrimes(numbers));
    MessageBox.Show(totalPrimes.ToString());
}

private int CalculatePrimes(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
    return numbers
          .AsParallel()
          .Where(n => Enumerable.Range(2, (int)Math.Sqrt(n) - 1).All(i => n % i != 0))
          .Count());
}
```

Comment: thanks it works perfectly! (especially I removed the extra closing ) after .Count in the cleaner version ;)

Answer (score 2):

Excerpt from Microsoft about [Chaining Tasks by Using Continuation Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288(v=vs.110).aspx):

> In asynchronous programming, it is very common for one asynchronous
>   operation, on completion, to invoke a second operation and pass data
>   to it. Traditionally, this has been done by using callback methods. In
>   the Task Parallel Library, the same functionality is provided by
>   *continuation* tasks. A continuation task (also known just as a
>   continuation) is an asynchronous task that is invoked by another task,
>   which is known as the *antecedent*, when the antecedent finishes.

Here is one way:

```
private void btnMultiThread_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var numbers = Enumerable.Range(2, range - 1);
    var totalPrimes = numbers
            .AsParallel()
            .Where(n => Enumerable.Range(2, (int)Math.Sqrt(n) - 1).All(i => n % i != 0))
            .Count();
        return totalPrimes;
    }).ContinueWith(() => MessageBox.Show(antecendent.Result.ToString()); // Antecedent result feeds into continuation
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to declare the antecendent in the continuation lambda in order to use it in the lambda body (antecendent => MessageBox.Show(antecendent.Result.ToString())?